# Cakephp/php Post Data Field Values Contains Segment From RAW Post

Tags: php, http, cakephp, nginx, cakephp-1.3

I was debugging a scenario where the POST request received by the server contains strings from RAW HTTP POST form data.
This request is coming from our android client and the issue is intermittent.
I logged the request using

`$this->log( print_r( $this->data, true ), 'debug' );`

Most of the times, the above saves right data, other times it is printing this:

```
[data] => Array (
    [field1] => 1-20--54LCEK02JjaI7QHrPGSG2MsqVN1N0H 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[field2]"

90-100
                    )
```

The above request is received by the server is what's making me nuts. My best guess is that it's something to do with form boundary.

Should I enable `always_populate_raw_post_data` in `php.ini` and debug in that direction using `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`

Please help darlings.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks! Also for such questions it would help if you'd show the actual raw request. I would suspect that either the body is malformed, or the content type is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to drill down to the root cause. The issue was due to proxy server in client's network changing the request.